# Angular Profiles extension - needed?

Tags: angular

Is the Angular Profiles extension needed in CiviCRM 5.64 onwards - apart from the CiviVolunteer extension?  I see there's a new release of the extension, but I can't work out whether it's required or not. I don't have the CiviVolunteer extension anymore so I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Angular Profiles Extension is not required by CiviCRM core or any extensions other than CiviVolunteer that I'm aware of (and probably a future version of CiviVolunteer will not need it either).